# C structure initialization - interesting

Tags: c, memory, malloc, structure

I have a C program which initializes two structures and tries to print their values. Please see the code below.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct node{
    int data;
    struct node * next;
}node_t;

typedef struct bstNode{
    int data;
    struct bstNode* right;
    struct bstNode* left;
}bstNode_t;

main(){
    struct bstNode* rootptr = malloc(sizeof(struct bstNode));

    printf("\n*rootptr  %x\n",*rootptr);
    printf("rootptr = %x\n",rootptr);

    rootptr->data = 8;
    rootptr->left = NULL;

    printf("\n*rootptr  %x\n",*rootptr);
    printf("rootptr = %x\n",rootptr);


    node_t* tmp = (node_t*) malloc(sizeof(node_t));

    printf("\n*tmp = %x",*tmp);
    printf("\n tmp = %x\n",tmp);

    tmp->data = 9;
    tmp->next = NULL;

    printf("\n*tmp = %x",*tmp);
    printf("\n tmp = %x\n",tmp);
    printf("\n ptr size = %x\n",sizeof(int));

}
```

The output of the program is

```
*rootptr  20fe1
rootptr = 4a78010

*rootptr  4691e000
rootptr = 4a78010

*tmp = 0
 tmp = 4a78030

*tmp = 9
 tmp = 4a78030

 ptr size = 4
```

Its surprising for me that `*rootptr` value differs, from *tmp. before and after assigning the value to the variable. Why is this happening? 
when *tmp can print the value as 9. why not *rootptr is not printing as 8 ?
here data is the first value in both the structures. so the value at the pointer (structure) should print the value of first data, right?

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: Don't use `%x` to print data pointer use `%p` instead. You can not print `struct node` object with `%x` similarly. Result of printing uninitialized value is not well defined and may be any garbage including but not limited to 0. Here you are getting first member printed, but it may print something else on some other target.

Comment: what do you mean `printf("\n*rootptr  %x\n",*rootptr);`? are you trying to print the value that data is holding?

Comment: we already helped you format the code. It’s almost done. Please take  the time and indent the second half of `main` to match the rest of the indentation.

Comment: here I am looking at the issue where I am able print *tmp as 9. but *rootptr as some junk. I expect it as 8. why is this happening?

Comment: @Dev May be you are lucky for `*tmp = 9` this case. If you don't dereference properly you wont get the proper output! So you are unlucky for `*rootptr`!

Comment: @Sathish, no. its not the matter. it has to do something with malloc. why because, if I comment out the struct node * right from bstNode structure declaration, it works good. it will print *rootptr as 8.

Comment: @Dev Oh! then try to typecast the memory allocation- `struct bstNode* rootptr = ( struct bstNode*) malloc (sizeof(struct bstNode));`

Comment: @Sathish, No. Even then its wrong. I am still not able to understand why this is happening. and I am sure that, there is a definite reason for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can not print the value of custom structs using

```
printf("\n*rootptr  %x\n",*rootptr);
printf("\n*tmp = %x",*tmp);
```

You should write a custom function and call it to print BST and node pointer.
For ex:

```
int print_node(node_t *nd)
{
  if(nd == 0) return printf("<null>");
  else return printf("[data = %d, next = %p]", nd->data, nd->next);
}
```

and later replace `printf("\n*rootptr  %x\n",*rootptr);` with

```
printf("\n*rootptr  ");
print_node(rootptr);
printf("\n");
```

Similarly you can write custom function to print BST node also.

About printf `%x` specifier, from man page

> o, u, x, X
>  The  **unsigned int argument** is converted to unsigned
>   octal (o), unsigned decimal (u), or unsigned hexadecimal (x and X)
>   notation.  The letters abcdef are used for x conversions; the letters ABCDEF are used for X conversions.  The precision, if any, gives the minimum number of digits that must appear; if the
>   converted value requires fewer digits, it is  padded  on  the
>                 left with zeros.  The default precision is 1.  When 0 is printed with an explicit precision 0, the output is empty.

If argument is not an unsigned int, you may get strange results.

Answer (score 0):

when you try to print the structure member value you should not use `*` operator to do this. Instead you should use `.` or `->` operator to do that based on its type!

Try this changes-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct node{
        int data;
        struct node * next;
}node_t;

typedef struct bstNode{
        int data;
        struct bstNode* right;
        struct bstNode* left;
}bstNode_t;

int main(){

        struct bstNode* rootptr = malloc(sizeof(struct bstNode)); // where rootptr is structure pointer. so you need do use -> operator to access ins members

        printf("\nrootptr->data  %d\n",rootptr->data); // Fix 1.
        printf("rootptr = %p\n",rootptr); // use %p to print addresses

        rootptr->data = 8;
        rootptr->left = NULL;

        printf("\nrootptr->data  %d\n",rootptr->data); // Fix 2.
        printf("rootptr = %p\n",rootptr);

        node_t* tmp = (node_t*) malloc(sizeof(node_t));

        printf("\ntmp->data = %d",tmp->data); // Fix 3.
        printf("\n tmp = %p\n",tmp);

        tmp->data = 9;
        tmp->next = NULL;

        printf("\ntmp->data = %d",tmp->data); // Fix 4.
        printf("\n tmp = %p\n",tmp);

        printf("\n ptr size = %x\n",sizeof(int));

        return 0;
}
```

Output-

```
rootptr->data  0
rootptr = 0x966a008

rootptr->data  8
rootptr = 0x966a008

tmp->data = 0
 tmp = 0x966a018

tmp->data = 9
 tmp = 0x966a018

 ptr size = 4
```

Comment: this I understand. but what I want to know is, why is the difference, when *tmp can print data as 9, why *rootptr cant print 8?

Answer (score 0):

The output is correct, and somehow by chance you got this result.... let me explain.

When you call "malloc", memory is allocated to you, but it is not initialized, so basically if memory was used before, it will be just "dirty" with some past values. You MUST always initialize your values, otherwise the content of the memory pointed will be dirty.

Now, let's see what you asked to the compiler:

```
printf("\n*rootptr  %x\n",*rootptr);
```

you basically asked to print a pointer (%x) but the parameter passed was a dereferenced pointer (*rootptr). In this case, printf will receive 4 bytes of dereferenced pointer: the first two bytes are the value of `rootptr->data`, the second two bytes are the value of `rootptr->left`

Since the value of both rootptr->data and rootptr->left (which is what you printed) are changing across time because you set some value, you have the output of *rootptr changing across time.

Same applies to `tmp`

In the second case, you asked

```
printf("rootptr = %x\n",rootptr);
```

So you asked the compiler to print the address of the pointer. This is corrects, and as you can see it will not change across your output

**Bottom line:** if your intention was to print the whole structure, you should have done something like:

```
printf("\nrootptr value %d,%x,%x\n",rootptr->data, rootptr->left, rootptr->right);
```

DO NOT EVER PRINT DE-REFERENCED POINTERS UNLESS YOU KNOW EXACTLY THE STRUCTURE

Comment: There is nothing wrong with printing dereferenced pointers. Printing a struct on the other hand... I don't think there is a format specifier for that!

Comment: `%x` is for printing unsigned ints. Trying to print a pointer with that causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: here I am looking at the issue where I am able print *tmp as 9. but *rootptr as some junk. I expect it as 8. why is this happening?